# Why curl and camel CouchDB producer component act differenly when we try to upload json file?

Tags: apache-camel, couchdb

I am uploading a json file into CouchDB. When I use curl with the following command:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -X POST -d @file1.json http://127.0.0.1:5984/order/_bulk_docs
```

the file store according to existing `_id` and each `_id` is a separate document in CouchDB.

**file1.json is:**

```
{"docs":[{
"_id": "pos-01-E001000",
"_rev": "100-86cbb4f843a8639a710c7ee7f5dc614c",
"orderId": null,
"customerName": "xyz"
},
{
"_id": "pos-01-D002000",
"_rev": "200-86cbb4f843a8639a710c7ee7f5dc614c", 
"orderId": null,
"customerName": "pqr"
}
]}
```

And when I use apache camel couch_db producer component i stores the entire file as a single document with auto-generate `_id` and `_rev`.
**MyRoute is:**

```
from("file:/home/r2/Desktop/couchInput?noop=true&fileName=file1.json")
             .bean(ProcessBean.class)    
             .to("couchdb:http://localhost:5984/order");
```

I want to store all data according to existing _id with separated each other with apache-camel.

How to save bulk documents in couchdb using apache-camel ?

I wish camel provide more flexibility in this case:
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using different endpoints in each case. With curl, you are (properly) using the `_bulk_docs` endpoint (`http://127.0.0.1:5984/order/_bulk_docs`) , which treats the JSON as a collection of individual documents.  In your second example, you're not using the `_bulk_docs` endpoint (instead you're using `http://127.0.0.1:5984/order`), so of course it treats your JSON as a single document.

Comment: So how do I tell camel to act my file as a **_bulk_docs**,I search everywhere as my perspective and I'm not getting any help or clue.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking/saying. `http` and `couchdb` are not endpoints.

Comment: Same error its showing: `org.lightcouch.CouchDbException: Bad Request{"error":"bad_request","reason":"Only reserved document ids may start with underscore."}`

Comment: The couchdb schema is :`couchdb:http://localhost:5984/dataBaseName/_Id/attachmentFileName"`

Comment: That error means you're using an invalid document ID--exactly as it says.  `_Id` is not a valid document ID, so if that URL is exactly what you're using, that is the problem.

Comment: I don't know why but I am kind of confused right now, Could you please provide one `sample -route` so I can proceed forward.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "sample -route", so no, I can't provide that. I've already answered your question. You've then asked multiple additional, and very confusing, questions.

Comment: I just asked,How to do with camel like I am doing with curl.I don't know why things went confusing.But I got answer for my posted question.